Task 'ijDownloadSources91ee8444-467' not found in root project 'projectABC' after clicking "Download Sources"
i got this error on macbook arm when click "dowload source". 
I often click on some Android file to read its code. However, they often require downloading via the "Download Sources" button. I have no problem with windows, linux, or intel macbook. however i got this error for macbook arm.
Error:
Task 'ijDownloadSources91ee8444-467' not found in root project 'projectABC'.

Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

